# Indeterminate form : $ 0 \cdot \infty$

Tags: integration, limits

I have a question about the limit of :
$$\lim_{t \to \infty}t\cdot e^{-t}$$

Why is that equal to $0$ ? Shoudln't $ 0 \cdot \infty$ be an inderminate form ?
It's true that with the graphic we can determine that this limit is equal to  $0$ :
[image]

But all I know is that  : $ 0 \cdot \infty$ is supposed to be an inderminate form .

Comment: ‘Indeterminate’ form doesn’t necessarily mean the limit can’t be zero.

Comment: "Indeterminate form" doesn't mean the limit can't exist.  It means that it might or might not exist, and if it does exist, it might have any value.  In this case, the limit exists and is equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ 0.\infty $ is of course an indeterminate form but in this particular case, it is zero.

Put $ t=\ln(u)$.

then

$$te^{-t}=\ln(u)e^{\ln(\frac 1u)}=\frac{\ln(u)}{u}$$

when $ t\to +\infty $, $ u\to +\infty$, and, as you know, $\frac{\ln(u)}{u}\to 0$

because, for $ u $ great enough, it is easy to prove that $ \ln(u)<\sqrt{u}.$

Comment: Thank you . This is what I needed to know .

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} te^{-t}=0$$
as your graph clearly shows. But: $$\int_0^\infty xe^{-x} dx =\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_0^t xe^{-x}dx=\lim_{t\to\infty}\bigg[1-e^{-t}(1+t)\bigg]=1$$

Your graph clearly shows the integral (area under the curve) is non-zero.

The answer to the broader question you pose about whether $0\cdot \infty$ is indeterminate is "Not necessarily".

Suppose $f(x)=x^2, g(x)=x$. Then $f(x)\to\infty, \frac{1}{g(x)}\to 0$, but $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=x\to\infty$

Swap the two functions around and we see $\frac{g(x)}{f(x)}=\frac 1x \to 0$

What the function converges to just depends on the rate of convergence of each side.

Answer (score 1):

A nice way to show this is:
$$f(t)=te^{-t}=\frac{t}{e^t}$$
and we know that:
$$e^t=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{t^n}{n!}=1+t+\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{t^3}{6}+...$$
and so:
$$f(t)=\frac{t}{1+t+t^2/2+t^3/3+...}=\frac{1}{1/t+1+t/2+t^2/3+...}$$
now if we look at this we can see that:
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac1t=0$$
and so on the bottom we have something of the form:
$$\frac 1{1+\infty+\infty+...}$$
which will obviously tend to $0$